# How to join 2 different graphs with different axes together side by side

Tags: r, par

How can I join 2 different graphs with different axes together at the side like in the graph below? Join them at the side without spacing and the Y axes have different labels for the graphs

[image: 2 different graphs with different Y and X axes joined together at the side]

Comment: Try searching here on SOverflow for ggplot2, grid and layout, depending on what you want to use.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Good suggestions by @thelatemail anyways, but you could also try [changing the par settings `mar` and `oma`](http://research.stowers-institute.org/mcm/efg/R/Graphics/Basics/mar-oma/index.htm).